# Is there a way to only add an error, if multiple validations fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am a beginner at ruby on rails. I am trying to add an error, only if multiple validations fail.

My initial idea is to use multiple unless with or operator.

```
class SomeValidator
  def validate(record)
    unless code.match(some_regex) || code.match(some_other_regex) || code.match(some_other_regex) 
      add error
    end
  end
end
```

it just doesn't seem right.

If I validate each validation separated, the validation will fail before the next one.

I don't know if it is clear, I want to see a way to for example,
validate a string to four different regexes, and add an error if all four regexes fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only execute some piece of logic if all four conditions fail, you'll want to use `&&` (logical `and`) and not `||` (logical `or`)

Comment: Thank you. I probably said it wrong, I want to add an error if none of these validations are true. If I added && so I would expect all the regexes to be true.

Comment: I will give you a real example. Suppose I receive an input string, I want to validate if it's a valid phone or a valid email. The problem is if I do each validation individually if the input is not a phone I would add an error, but it's not my desire. I just want to add an error if the input is none of the desired validations.

Comment: By the way, my code is accomplishing what I want, I just think I am breaking the single responsibility of my validator. I was thinking of adding a PhoneValidator and an email validator and grouping them somehow, to just add an error if none of them are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array#none?` it should return true if all elements are false. for example:

```
add error if [condition_1, condition_2, condition_3].none?
```

Or as mentioned by @inyl

```
add error unless condition_1 && condition_2 && condition_3
```

`unless` is confusing, I would avoid it for complex conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array#any?`

```
unless [code.match?(some_regex), code.match?(some_other_regex)].any?
  add error
end
```

If some of conditions is `true`, `any?` return `true`

If all conditions are `false`, `any?` return `false`

BTW if you don't need `MatchData` object it's better to use `match?`, not `match`